# Does MySQL processes run in user or kernel modes?

Tags: kernel, mysql, system-calls

I try to count IOPS and I/O size with SystemTap script and use MySQL to be workload.

I found `mysqld` doesn't call systemcall but `mysqld` has read/write on VFS.

So, do MySQL processes run in user or kernel modes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysql doesn't have a kernel module, therefore it runs in user mode.

Perhaps what you are seeing is that mysql is using memory-mapped files instead of calling read/write.  So, accessing a page of memory causes a read/write without using a syscall.

Or, perhaps you called strace without "-f" to follow the child processes?